# Symfony2 send image created with imagecreate() via response(httpfoundation)

Tags: php, symfony, captcha

I want to send simple image through httpgoundation response, from one controller to another. Here's my code:

```
    $string = (string)md5(uniqid());
    $string = substr($string, 0, $length);

    $image = imagecreate(200, 50);
    imagefill($image, 0, 0, "#000000");

    $headers= array(
        'Content-type'=>'image/jpeg',
        'Pragma'=>'no-cache',
        'Cache-Control'=>'no-cache'
    );

    $response = new Response( $image, 200, $headers );

    return new Response($response);
```

The error says `The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString()`. Seeking the answer using google I only found people who want to return file somewhere from server(an asset). What should I do to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `return $response;` instead of `return new Response($response);`

And you have to convert image resource to string. Do the following:

```
    $string = (string)md5(uniqid());
    $string = substr($string, 0, $length);

    $image = imagecreate(200, 50);
    imagefill($image, 0, 0, "#000000");

    $headers= array(
        'Content-type'=>'image/jpeg',
        'Pragma'=>'no-cache',
        'Cache-Control'=>'no-cache'
    );

    ob_start();
    imagejpeg($img);
    $imageString = ob_get_clean();

    return new Response( $imageString, 200, $headers );
```

Comment: seems like working, thanks! But now in that another controller do you have any idea how to convert it to image, because I've got like a big, strange string. I used `imagecreatefromstring()` but it returned only something like:  `Resource id #11`